# android FileNotFound Exception

Tags: android, file-io

The file model.obj is in the assets directory of my project. The toast that comes out is a File Not Found exception. I am running the program on my Galaxy S3 not a virtual device. Do I have to specify some path to the file?

**Code:**

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Date;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.app.Activity;

    public class ImportOBJ {

        protected void onCreate(String filename,Context context) 
        {
            try
            {
                FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);  
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

                String line = null, input="";

                while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) 
                {
                    input += line;
                }

                reader.close(); 
                fis.close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

**ManActivity:**

```
   package com.example.tictactoeshowgrid;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ImportOBJ obj_import=new ImportOBJ();
            obj_import.onCreate("model.obj",MainActivity.this);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to get the file from asset manager:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = null;

try {
    inputStream = assetManager.open("foo.txt");
    if ( inputStream != null)
        Log.d(TAG, "It worked!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
```

Can be replaced with

```
InputStream fis = context.getAssets().open(filename);
```

---

`GetAssets()` returns an [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html):

> Provides access to an application's raw asset files; see [Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) for the way most applications will want to retrieve their resource data. This class presents a lower-level API that allows you to open and read raw files that have been bundled with the application as a simple stream of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

the path is assets/file/model.obj, you can read file like this

```
InputStream fis = mContext.getAssets().open("file/model.obj");
```